# How to pass the value of Firebase to the next activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We've got a key to listview from Firebase.
To view the value in the next Acitivity when key is selected
How do I declare to putExtra?

example)

Book

- 1:aaa
- 2:bbb
- 3:ccc
- 4:ddd

Listview

1

2

3

4 << select

I want to see ddd at next activity.

**LoadActivity.java**

```
package com.dogeun.auth;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class LoadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
private ListView mListview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load);


    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseAuth = mFirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1);
    mListview.setAdapter(adapter);

    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Book/" + mFirebaseUser.getUid())
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

In this part, the value is 
How can I get it to putExtra?

```
    mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this, LoadtextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("text",?????);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }) ;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

please help me

Comment: Can you use adapter.getItem(position) ?

Comment: I tried it but select 1 to print 1 in Textview.

Comment: When you add it directly to adapter, try creating an ArrayList of books instead, and then when you need to get the item you can use list.get(position), right now you are trying to create an object of two individual strings (key and value) but they are not connected, so when you try to get the key, you are missing the value

Comment: I'm sorry. 
I don't understand.ㅠㅠ
Can you explain it in code?

Comment: private List<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();            

public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mList.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    }
            
intent.putExtra("text",mList.get(position));

This method Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding value twice in your adapter for same item/child.

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());

    // you should add it only once and get value by using adapter.getItem(position) and send that to other activity
}
```

See my answer in comment in your code above

Comment: This was the code for the test. Now 'adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());' is missing.